# how to melt tibbles?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble, melt

I have a dataframe where one of the columns has a tibble inside it as a value. It looks like this
[click here to see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8JhE.png)

I tried to eexport this dataframe to csv file but then the tibbles can't be read on excel, then I tried to to export to xlsx file but I get the error : `Error in if (is.na(value)) { : the condition has length > 1`

My second problem is, I want to convert the tibbles to actual line and columns, so for each tibble, the first 4 columns would be repeated as much as needed for the column that contains the tibble to be replaced by the columns of the tibble but I don't know how to do that ! maybe using mutate?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `unnest_wider` or `unnest` i.e. `library(tidyr);library(dplyr);df1 %>% unnest(outcomes)`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be with `tidyr::unnest()`:

```
df %>%
  unnest(outcomes)
```